# Heavyocity evolve sound design

Tags: sampling, kontakt

Anyone have any idea what their workflow is like? I would LOVE to just see a dissection of like, a single patch even just to see how much of it is straight audio, how much is script, whatever. Would be so insightful.

EDIT: I was more just talking about how they make their source stuff, if I was unclear.

Comment: Pro tip: a sampler plays back "straight audio". There's really not much "script magic" apart from what makes the instrument playable using a keyboard.

Comment: I'm aware what a sampler does, thank you. First off, their is scripting in their stuff. What I actually meant was some of the sample production.

Comment: Actually, Kontakt is capable of much more than just playing back straight audio; there is quite a lot of sound design possibilities that are possible through the use of lfo's, envelopes, pitch-shifting, and even sequencing.  This can be further explored through the use of scripts (in other words, "script magic" is entirely possible, imho).  I haven't used Heavyocity myself, so I don't really have an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents as Kontakt library deveper:
As far as I can see from Evolve demos and videos, seems there's isn't much of "script magic" there. Seems to be a very basic script to control filter, EG parameters and FX triggering. I can guess all samples has been pre-processed and mapped to Kontakt for further mangling using the provided interface.

About source stuff: I can guess is almost "standard" techniques used to make SD impacts, whooshes, big booms and so on. (record, layer, process, goto 1)

IMHO ;)

Cheers,
Luca